# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:

Tags: java, android, json, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm new in android and I want to send editText value using JSON to server . I get this error "StringIndexOutOfBoundsException" and I don't know how can fix it. Here is My code :

JSONParser.java

```
package com.example.bookstore;


public class JSONParser  {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method.equals("POST")){

                HttpClient httpclient = getNewHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
                if(httpResponse != null){
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
                }

            }else if(method.equals("GET")){
                // request method is GET
                HttpClient httpclient = getNewHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
                if(httpResponse != null){
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
                }
            }           


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            if(reader != null){
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json.substring(json.indexOf("{"), json.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }


    public HttpClient getNewHttpClient() {
        try {
            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            trustStore.load(null, null);

            SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
            sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

            SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
            registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
            registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

            ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);

            return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new DefaultHttpClient();
        }
    }
}
```

Sale.java

```
package com.example.bookstore;

public class Sale extends Activity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
EditText BookName;
EditText AuthorName;
EditText Publication;
EditText Price;
EditText BookGenre;

// url to create new product
private static String url_create_product = "https://5.144.130.36/android/create_product.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    setContentView(R.layout.sale);

    BookName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.BookName);
    AuthorName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.AuthorName);
    Publication = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Publication);
    Price = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Price);
    BookGenre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.BookGenre);


    Button confirm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Confirm);


    confirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating new product in background thread
            new CreateNewBook().execute();
        }
    });
}

class CreateNewBook extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Sale.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Book Submition");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
          runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
        String B_Name = BookName.getText().toString();
        String Au_Name = AuthorName.getText().toString();
        String Pub = Publication.getText().toString();
        String Pr = Price.getText().toString();
        String B_Genre = BookGenre.getText().toString();


        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("B_Name", B_Name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Au_Name", Au_Name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Pub", Pub));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Pr", Pr));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("B_Genre", B_Genre));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            } 
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

                }
     });

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (pDialog != null) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog = null;
    }
}

}
```

Logcat

```
04-29 11:13:59.536: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=58; regionStart=-1; 
regionLength=1
04-29 11:13:59.536: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at   
java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:583)
04-29 11:13:59.536: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at   
java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1464)
04-29 11:13:59.536: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at   
com.example.bookstore.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:109)
```

I have MySSLSocketFactory class to certification that I don't think any problem exists in there.

Comment: please add exception logs

Answer (score 2):

```
jObj = new JSONObject(json.substring(json.indexOf("{"), json.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
```

Why do you add 1 to the last index? if you receive a `String` where the last `}` is really on the last index, you have a `OutOfBounds`.

Answer (score 0):

I will edit my answer after you will paste your logs, however I think that the issue is with the :

```
jObj = new JSONObject(json.substring(json.indexOf("{"), json.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
```

or with a similar fragment with string operations.
Change this line to:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
stringBuilder.append("{");
stringBuilder.append(StringUtils.substringBeforeLast(StringUtils.substringAfter(json, "{"), "}"));
stringBuilder.append("}");
jObj = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
```

This piece is entirely StringOutOfBoundsException and NullPointerException safe.

According to: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html

Comment: `StringUtils.substringBetween()` finds the first matching occurance, which is not the intended functionality (i guess)